# JQuery Tag-it plugin connect to database?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, tags

I am testing this JQuery plugin "Tag-it" by Levy Carneiro in my ASP MVC application.

Website: http://levycarneiro.com/2010/03/tag-it-tag-suggestions-editor-and-autocomplete-in-a-jquery-ui-plugin/

I want the plugin to fetch tags that i have in my mssql database and i wonder how to connect to it if someone could help?

Now, my javascript looks like this:

```
$('#mytags').tagit({

   availableTags: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby", "python", "c", "scala", "groovy", "haskell", "perl"]

 });
```

how should i write to connect to the address '/Questions/GetTags' ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/Questions/GetTags',
   dataType: 'json',
   success:function (data){
      //data should be a json object that returns an array
      $('#mytags').tagit({
        availableTags: data
      });
   }
});
```

**PHP** SERVER side or find asp equivalent

```
<?php 

$tag = array('json','java','javascript');
echo json_encode($tag);

?>
```

To explain :

Your telling to fetch an ajax page, that returns a json object. and then you are telling that the input `#mytags` should be a `tagit` ui, and then the tag it should have the json object to be its tags `availableTags`

Comment: if I would like to fill tagit with tags when the page loads, how does that work?

Comment: ok $.ajax makes a page request and it returns some text back called json its like, html, or xml, but different on its on right, so tagit expects availableTags to have an array of data, so learn the process of jquery, i would say

Comment: the php array should be like this....                              $tag = array("tags"=>array('json','java','javascript'));    or instead of data.tags use only data